# Freeze on login screen

Tags: release-hera, greeter

hope you are doing well.
Elementay os just make to login screen where mouse and keyboard doesn't work but the text area for the password is flashing and after some second it stop, so I'm guessing it freeze and I'm forced to hard reboot (rebooting doesn't fix the issue, it's just the only thing I can do from there).

I've tried to make the video driver load after boot time adding "nomodeset" to the grub and disabling csm as founded somewhere on the web but still nothing.

I've tried even a different keyboard but both of them work on windows.

Have you ever encountered a similar issue? if not any advice/log that i can look at to try to understand what's going on?
Booting to advanced mode I'm able to access a shell but not internet, dunno why.

I've event tried to reinstall the whole thing but the thumb drive I've used after showing elementary logo go black.

Hope in the community.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your ISO is corrupted. 
To verify it's integrity run the following command in the terminal, as per the instructions found [here](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download):

```
sha256sum elementaryos-5.1-stable.20200405.iso
```

It should produce the output:

```
cc46be42a1629069e18ab9a49a62fd36a9402036fb078f085b3151d06c10019b
```

If that's not the case, download it again, preferably the torrent version.